# AssumeRole - AWS iOS SDK sample

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I am using "AssumeRole"  api in iOS AWS sdk to generate temporary security credentials. Can anybody tell the steps for this or give sample app for this?

```
 TSC = [[AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient alloc]initWithAccessKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" withSecretKey:@"uuuuuuuuuuuyyyyyyyy" ]; 
 request = [[SecurityTokenServiceAssumeRoleRequest alloc]init ]; 
    request.roleArn = @"arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/test";
    request.roleSessionName = @"test";
    request.policy =nil;
    request.durationSeconds=[NSNumber numberWithInt:3600];
    request.externalId=@"test123";
    response =  [TSC assumeRole:request];
```

My doubt is to get temporary credentials, the above code will be enough  or  do i need call the NSURLConnection delegates explicitly to make the web service call? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should be enough to get credentials.  If the request is successful, the credentials will be available in the response object. ([API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/SecurityTokenServiceAssumeRoleResponse.html)).

You'll need to initialize a AmazonCredentials object to use the returned credentials:

```
AmazonCredentials *credentials = 
   [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:response.credentials.accessKeyId
                                  withSecretKey:response.credentials.secretAccessKey
                              withSecurityToken:response.credentials.sessionToken];

AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials];
```